# Sorting dynamically created data in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, sorting, cocoa, nstableview

I have an NSTableView that contains several columns, each of which I've setup to be sortable by mapping the column's sort key to a property in my model and providing a compare: selector. This works perfectly for those columns that have a direct mapping to an NSString or NSInteger property in my model.

However, I have a couple of columns that are, effectively, aggregates of model data — i.e. my objectValueForTableColumn method will dig into the model and often uses two or more properties to generate the appropriate NSString to be displayed within that row/column.

I've been trying to get these columns to sort, but I'm not sure what goes into the sort key or selector. I've tried using one of the property names, tried using compare:, etc... but the code either does nothing or generates an exception.

I've read through Apple's documentation on NSTableView sorting and searched the web for examples, but it's not entirely clear how this situation should be handled. How do I map these columns to a key, and how does the comparison take place. As mentioned, the data displayed in the table is a string, which would seem to be sortable via compare:, or is there some mechanism for providing a custom compare function?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to sort the data? Is it possible to add a calculated property or a compare selector to the data model (in a catagory)? Do you want to use a custom sort descriptor?

Comment: I want to sort the data displayed alphabetically. Yes, I thought about simply adding an NSString to the model and storing the generated string there at the time the table is populated, but that seemed... almost like a workaround? Like any programming challenge you can usually find at least three ways to solve a problem, but I'm hoping for a "this is how it should be done solution". A custom sort descriptor would be great if someone could point me to a good resource.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa provides built in sort descriptors, but these only handle basic data types: strings, dates, numbers. In your case, you will need to define a custom sort descriptor and pass that to the table - your data model is not a simple data type. All a sort descriptor does is take two values and reports back whether value 1 is greater than value 2, less than, or if they are equal. It would look something like this:

```
- (NSSortDescriptor*)myCustomSortDescriptor
{
    if (_myCustomSortDescriptor == nil) {
        NSComparisonResult (^myModelSortBlock)(id, id) = ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
            //
            // Here you have two objects from your model, i.e. the
            // the two rows that NSTableView wants to check the order of.
            // This is where your custom comparison goes. Then you return one of:
            // 
            if (obj1 < obj2)
                return NSOrderedAscending;
            else if (obj1 > obj2)
                return NSOrderedDescending;
            else
                return NSOrderedSame; // they must be the same
        };
        _myCustomSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self"
                                                                ascending:YES
                                                               comparator:myModelSortBlock];
    }
    return _myCustomSortDescriptor;
}
```

I've packaged this in a method for convenience, but you can define it anywhere you want. You then pass your custom sort descriptor to the table.